# Display editable value in react bootstrap Form.Control

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap input which renders a list of value `onChange` of the input. And if a user selects a value from the list i want to show it in my input field. But it should have a ability to type again on the input field if necessary (to select another value). I'm using react-bootstrap and my approach is as follows

```
searchConsumer = (e) => {
        const {consumer} = this.props;
        let consumerValue = e.target.value;
        const data = {
            "filterText": consumerValue,
            "page": 1,
            "maxRecords": this.state.maxRecords
        }
        consumer(data);
    }

selectConsumer(name){
        this.setState({
            selectedValue:name
        })
    }

    renderConsumerList(){
        const {consumers} = this.props;
        if(consumers.consumerData.length > 0) {
            return consumers.consumerData.map(item =>{
                return (
                <div className="consumer_search_item" onClick={()=>this.selectConsumer(item.name)}>{item.name}</div>
                )
            })
        }
    }

<Form.Control type="search" onChange={(e)=>this.searchConsumer(e)} value={consumers.consumerData.length > 0 ? selectedValue : ''} className="modal_input" placeholder="Search any consumer by name" required />

<div className="consumer_result_container">{this.renderConsumerList()}</div>
```

I can set the value successfully if i select a value from the list. But if i want to change it i cannot change it because the value is already set in the input field and does not let me delete or edit the value. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens is when onChange (searchConsumer) is called, the new value that is typed is not updating state:

```
searchConsumer = ( e ) => {
    const { consumer } = this.props;
    let consumerValue = e.target.value;
    const data = {
        "filterText": consumerValue,
        "page": 1,
        "maxRecords": this.state.maxRecords
    }
    consumer( data );

    // Update state because new value is typed
    this.setState({
        inputValue: consumerValue
    })
}
```

Form.Control value should reflect the state:

```
<Form.Control type="search" onChange={ ( e ) => this.searchConsumer( e ) } value={ consumers.consumerData.length > 0 ? this.state.inputValue : '' }    />
```

Comment: Yes that was it.Thanks